# Google Chrome text shadow rendering

Tags: google-chrome, css

Google Chrome has an extremely annoying defect in its implementation of CSS3 text-shadow. The sub-pixel antialiasing is turned off when text-shadow is applied. No amount of -webkit-font-smoothing will persuade it otherwise. The crude alpha-channel anti-alias leads to shadow intermixing with the letters and this along with the pixelated text ends up producing a very ugly look. This is even more evident if hand writing fonts are used such as Monotype Corsiva http://www.newfonts.net/index.php?pa=show_font&id=130

One of the places you can see this clearly is on Twitter - http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth. The text-shadow is used for text outline there: view the page in Chrome, compare with FF or IE, you will see how bad it is.

The effect gets even worse with smaller text until it renders it completely unreadable. Technical discussion of the issue is available here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?fid=5d1c0f2082af0f21000483e9a516d36e&hl=en

There is a bug submitted in the Chromium project (issue 23440). This bug has been around more than a year and is still not assigned to anybody. Google devs saw it, decided it is not so important and left it to age. It turns out they only fix the "popular" bugs, a practice so lame that it looks impressive! I am very disappointed with Chrome! Web typography and CSS3 are used by more and more people every day to make the web much more beautiful place! It is a shame such issue exists to slow that down.

So, a public effort is needed to get this one fixed. Tell others about this, write in your blogs. You can go at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23440 and vote for the issue. You can do that by clicking at the star located at top left page side (Some type of Google account required - gmail, etc).

To make things more clear - my question has two goals:

1. Find a technical workaround.
2. Make Google fix the issue in Chrome.

I will vote up every link posted to an article about the issue and mark as accepted the best one tech solution or public effort.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[@sebastian's fix](http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/NfmU7/6/) may not work for old versions of Chrome.
Screenshot under Iron Browser (Chromium fork) v3.0.197.0:
                                                          [image]
All the ones that have been assigned a shadow look the same and `-webkit-font-smoothing` has no effect as well as `-webkit-text-stroke`.

Instead, I've experimented until I've come up with this fix: http://jsbin.com/acalu4

**tldr:** add an innocuous `0 0 0 transparent,` before your other shadow(s).

*Known issues:* some browsers can only handle 1 `text-shadow`. In order not to affect them (killing their only shadows) this should be applied via javascript only to Chrome.

Comment: Thanks :) solved my problem. Which browsers can only handle one `text-shadow`? If it's the minority, I wouldn't advocate using javascript to apply this.

Comment: This bothered me too, until I saw this answer and it fixed it -- then I laughed out loud. Thanks, man!

Comment: @JGarrido You're right. Unfortunately Google fixed the bug, and I liked it because bigger font sizes looked smoother with shadows on Windows :( There seems to be other problems related to text shadows, look in the comments [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23440) (such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23440#c39)).

Comment: @Ben Maybe you're right, I only know of Safari 3 not supporting multiple text shadows. For me that represents the same user base as if it were something like MSIE 4.0.

Answer (score 11):

the first part (technical workaround): Giving the text a thin stroke.

try this css, you might have to tweak the values to get the desired effect.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; /* or antialiased; */
-webkit-text-stroke: .10pt black; /* or 0.01em might be better */
```

only webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) read it, so it won't affect FF or IE.

play with an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/NfmU7/6/

Comment: Sorry to say it does not work. -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; is the default anyway, setting it to antialiased does not seem to make a difference. webkit-text-stroke is actually drawn INSIDE the text, the letters are very thin, and so nothing should make them thinner. The actual problem I have with Chrome is that the shadow is cast upon the neighboring letters instead of besides them as it should be. I will update my question.

Comment: it works.. on Mac: http://christophzillgens.com/en/articles/-webkit-font-smoothing-reloaded

Comment: Maybe it works on making the text more readable, but my problem is actually not with the text, but with its shadow. Without the text-shadow the text if perfectly OK. And yes, antialiased does not have any effect on windows yet.

Comment: @Avok: using text-stroke is the only solution i can think of to making the text more readable. it's a shame that the text-stroke declaration doesn't let us specify how to place the text-stroke (inside, outside, centered).  it is centered by default. Still, it does make the text more readable, no?

Comment: You must remove the shadow in order for the text-stroke to be any good. It would make the text more readable on a low contrast background if I could specify it with enough thickness. But I cannot unfortunately, as it goes inside the text. I don't know what you mean by centered? Is it supposed to be in the middle of a letter?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this. It seems to work in Safari 4+, Chrome (tested on 8.0x) and Firefox 3.5.

Try it:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 
             0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 
             1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 
             0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Comment: How does that fix work? Could you care to elaborate? It seems that it will create four shadows instead of one? What exactly is the the fix? The four shadows? This exact parameters, smth. like magic numbers? What happens with my shadow declaration when I add this one? Do I remove it?

Comment: @avok00.
What I know is that this works. If I am not mistaken, each group is placing the shadow top, right, bottom, left.
Then, I am sure you know this but text-shadow syntax uses X-offset, Y-offset, blur and colour (rgb and a for alpha of course).

So, in my post above, we don't use blur, because the shadow is being drawn top, right, bottom and left.

text-shadow: *TOP* x-offset y-offset rgba(0,0,0,0.75), *RIGHT* x-offset y-offset rgba(0,0,0,0.75) etc...

I hope this helps and is clear enough!

Comment: I am wrong. It's nothing to do with top, right, bottom, left but rather multiple levels of shading. Chris Spooner has a great set of demos here: http://line25.com/articles/using-css-text-shadow-to-create-cool-text-effects. Check out the Fire sample!

Comment: OK, that is all fine, four shadows with no blur, but how does that fix my problem? Where do I apply this piece of code? What happens with my already defined shadow? Are you saying that those four shadows recreate the effect of one shadow with blur? When the shadows does not use blur, is that a workaround for the text subpixel rendering bug? Where did you see that fix?