# css text-shadow in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/), I've applied a text shadow to the headings which looks good in Firefox:

[image]

But it looks awful in Chrome v.17

[image]

I saw [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046142/google-chrome-text-shadow-rendering) and changed the text shadow style from

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
```

to:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent, 1px 1px 1px black;
```

But it made no difference. Is there anything I can do to improve the way the text shadows are rendered in Chrome? Ideally, I'd like them to look the same in Chrome as they do in Firefox.

Comment: it's work fine. I am using chrome 17 on mac ox

Comment: It seems that when Chrome renders shadows it somehow makes "m" a more narrow letter. Try setting `color:rgba(0,0,0,0)` and you'll see what I mean. Whatever you do afterwards to `text-shadow` letters stay malformed. Also mind the fact that if you change font from Verdana to ie. Arial, shadow seems alright. So I suppose it could be something with type vectors... Maybe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I would slightly change the shadow. Changing it to:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black;
```

Seems to solve problem here in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that Firefox and Chrome render text-shadow differently. I was able to use this and it seemed like it did help a bit:

```
.logo {
 text-shadow: 1px 0 0 black;
}
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6C9d.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcsf5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
   text-shadow: 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 
     0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 
     1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 
     0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me.

Chrome 17.0.963.
Firefox 11.0

Dunno what's wrong. Try increasing the font size.!

Answer (score 0):

check this out may help a bit im not sure though. It seems you may have anti-aliasing issues and someone helped me fix anti-aliasing in every browser..

check it:
[Antialiased text in Firefox after CSS rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714778/antialiased-text-in-firefox-after-css-rotation?noredirect=1#comment33018285_21714778)

This incorporates including translate3d(0px,0px,1px) so that the graphic processor handles the processing and softens the aliasing

Answer (score 0):

**text-shadow** is must be in below format :

```
textShadow = color horizontalShadow(px) verticalShadow(px) blur(px);
```

example :

text-shadow: rgb(246, 0, 0) 5px 3px 8px;

output : 
[image]