# Antialiased text in Firefox after CSS rotation

Tags: css, firefox

[image]

so I've read a lot about the current state of rotating text and not being able to perfectly get real antialiasing to happen in all browsers. It looks like the first box in the pic in chrome, but the second, jaggedy box in firefox. I've tried the most popular fixes including -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; and maybe one other I can't remember.

However this is not asking the same question, but a new one I havent found anywhere. These two screenshots of the same box are both taken from Firefox. The jaggedy box on the bottom is what it looks like normally, however, when I mess with the rotation attributes with another(completely different) element on the page with the css edit console, it renders the box perfect / smoothly...

I do, however, have to continue to press up or down to change the rotation value on another element for the entire box to render antialiased perfectly, then it returns to its jaggedy normal self. I rotated the div that the content is in and put the css fixes on the same div(although I did try putting the css fixes on every element) and I didn't ever seem to get any smoothness or antialising like you see in the box above...only when I rotate another element on the page in the browser. WTF?!!?!? is there a way to do this in css or is it only something the browser is doing in realtime and cannot reproduce that smoothness in CSS yet?

EDIT: PIC for comments section[image]

Comment: What version/OS are you using? I've recreated your demo and it looks well anti-aliased on my FF27/Win7: [data URL](data:text/html, <div style="margin-top:5em;margin-left:1em;float: left; border: medium solid; padding: 0px 1em; border-radius: 1em; transform: rotate(-30deg);"><h1>This is heading</h1><p>This is body text</p></div>)

Comment: Sorry, can't get the data url to link properly in the comment. Just copy from `(` to `)` exclusive and paste in the url bar.

Comment: wow! I never knew you could do things like that through the url, thanks! However its still jaggedy. On my mac on both chrome / ff its fine but on Win7 FF27 I still get bad text. Its harder to notice without all the styles I put on mine, but you can still see a wavy baseline and some pixellation on the font. I uploaded a screenshot above

Comment: I see what you mean in the screenshot. I think it's likely your FF27/Win7 is not using cleartype. I have `Options>Advanced>Use hardware acceleration` checked; also in `about:config` all keys starting with `gfx.font` are defaults except `gfx.font_rendering.directwrite.enabled` which is `true`. Maybe try those settings?

Comment: Also, AFAIK only Firefox supports `text/html` data URLs in the location bar, which is sad, because they're pretty neat.

Comment: Hmm yea I tried all the settings and they were already on. I think it must be just that the webpage or element gets a bit blurry(which is antialiasing in a basic sense) when you move the rotation value in the inspector in firefox and the actual display element doesnt allow for perfect antialiasing yet in FF. Strange though that the browser would show this behavior at all if it doesnt support css that corrects the real issue. I've seen lots of posts about antialiasing issues when text is rotated I just thought I might have found something that would lead to fixing it, maybe not

Comment: I had another thought: it could be related to creating an opengl/webgl layer behind the scenes. If you add `translate3d(0px,0px,1px)` after the rotate transform, does it "fuzz out" a bit more?

Comment: You are the shit!! That worked perfectly. Chrome stays the same nice antialiased and firefox now looks the same. All browsers are perfectly antialiased! So how does that work, is it something to do with the z-axis? I read it might be triggering hardware acceleration, but how does that help with antialiasing?

Comment: No worries Mike! So with the z-transform the rotated element's now in a gfx layer stored separately in GPU memory. I guess when it goes to render, it must compute the transparencies on partially-covered pixels a bit better; if it were static it'd just .. get the normal jagged-y text renderer to do it ..? (Sorry, this isn't really my area.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For whatever reason, it seems under some circumstances browsers "forget" to antialias text while doing complex transforms.

### The fix:

Using CSS to force the browser to render the transformed element in a separately-composited "layer" is one solution:

```
transform: rotate(…) translate3d(0px,0px,1px);
```

### The explanation:

Many rendering engine implementations create a GPU layer for the 3d-transformed element, and composite it onto the rest of the page when painting. This alternate rendering path can force a different text-rendering strategy, resulting in better antialiasing.

### The caveat:

However, this is a bit of a hack: first, we're asking for a 3-dimensional transform we don't really want; second, forcing many unnecessary GPU layers can degrade performance, especially on mobile platforms with limited RAM.

[dev.opera.com hosts a good discussion](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/) of compositing, hacks using `transform3d`, and the CSS3 `will-change` property.

Comment: Did you mean: ```transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 1px)```?

Comment: @Micros yep, well spotted. Actually, the question implies an existing `transform: rotate(…)`, and the `translate3d` should append to that rule, which is again potentially confusing so I will edit to include the full rule

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy if you come back and answer this I can give the answer to you. just realized I hadn't had an answer to this so I needed to put something here.

This solution worked as in the comments above:

Jeremy:
I had another thought: it could be related to creating an opengl/webgl layer behind the scenes. If you add translate3d(0px,0px,1px) after the rotate transform, does it "fuzz out" a bit more?

Answer - Yes this works to perfectly anti-alias any text in all browsers!

Comment: I think I might - partly for the magic internet points, but also because it's hard to find a question you've commented on.