# Angled div background with linear and radial gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients, css-shapes, radial-gradients

I am currently using CSS3 to make an div with the left side angled like a trapezium using the following CSS adapted from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hfkk7/5/):

```
background:linear-gradient(75deg, transparent 75px, #35753f 76px);
```

I would like to combine the following CSS background with a radial one, to create the effect shown in the image below. However, when I do this, I lose the angled side. What is the best way to combine these two backgrounds?

Here is the radial background:

```
background:radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at right center, #337540 0%, #003832 100%);
```

Here is what it should look like:

[image: Desired look]

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhfkpryc/) of the below:

```css
.container {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#top-banner {
  position: relative;
}
#top-banner .container {
  height: 350px;
}
#top-banner #banner-right {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(75deg, transparent 75px, #35753f 76px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(75deg, transparent 75px, #35753f 76px);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(75deg, transparent 75px, #35753f 76px);
  background: linear-gradient(75deg, transparent 75px, #35753f 76px);
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
#top-banner #banner-right:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  width: 5000px;
  left: 350px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
  background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(left center, circle closest-corner, #337540 0%, #003832 100%);
  /* Mozilla Firefox */
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(left center, circle closest-corner, #337540 0%, #003832 100%);
  /* Opera */
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(left center, circle closest-corner, #337540 0%, #003832 100%);
  /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, left center, 0, left center, 140, color-stop(0, #337540), color-stop(1, #003832));
  /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left center, circle closest-corner, #337540 0%, #003832 100%);
  /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
  background-image: ;
  z-index: -100;
}
/*#top-banner #banner-right {
 width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background:black;
    position:relative;
 float: right; 
}
#top-banner #banner-right:before {
 content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-bottom: 350px solid white; 
    border-right: 40px solid transparent; 
}*/

#top-banner .slider {
  float: left;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="top-banner">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div id="banner-right">
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9aQmrN3-xpQ/TuYsXHQygrI/AAAAAAAAAtw/cEmz4PgEQdQ/s1600/r-NEW-SPECIES-MEKONG-DELTA-huge.jpg" height="350" alt="banner-1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried multiple backgrounds?

Comment: I've tried comma separating the linear and radial backgrounds, but the radial background always forces the left edge to be straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Angled div - 2 methods

The angle is created with `transform: rotate` and not the linear-gradient.

### #1 -  Rotated `:before` with translate 3d

In this example, `translate3d(0px,0px,1px)` is used to eliminate the jagged edge of the rotated element. [More information here.](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/) I was reminded about this technique [from this answer dealing with a similar rendering problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521679/2930477)

As this is a hack that should be used sparingly, their is an alternative way to mask this edge without it in the second example.

- Rotate a pseudo element, `:before`, of the div. This will create our angled edge
- The `:before` gets an appropriate percentage height, `width: 100px` and is positioned appropriately
- The parent div is given `overflow: hidden` to cut off the background cleanly
- Create a second pseudo element, `:after`, to extend the background to the edge of the viewport.
- The gradient background is applied to `:after`
- The `:before` pseudo element is given a solid background the same color as the edge of the gradient to blend
- The `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are given `z-index: 1`
- Elements that will sit above the "background" will need `position: relative` and `z-index: 2` to push them above it. (Like the paragraph in the example below)

#### Example

The linear-gradient on the body demonstrates that the div can be placed over any background.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#000 0%, #FFF 100%) no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 100px;
  min-width: 500px;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 120%;
  width: 90px;
  top: -10%;
  left: 90px;
  background: #003832;
  transform:  translate3d(0px,0px,1px) rotate(-15deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 120%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -10%;
  left: 135px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 50% 50%, #33753E 0%, #003832 80%);
  z-index: 1;
}
p {
  color: #FFF;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```

---

### #2 - Rotated `:before` and `:after` without translate 3d

- Rotate a pseudo element, `:before`, of the div
- Apply the background to the pseudo element
- The pseudo element gets `height: 200%` and `width: 200%` and is positioned appropriately
- The parent div is given `overflow: hidden` to cut off the gradient cleanly and the rotated pseudo element becomes the background
- A second pseudo element, `:after`, is used to help mask the jagged edge with a box-shadow (the left edge is jagged at all rotations that are not 45deg increments)
- The `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are given `z-index: 1`
- Elements that will sit above the "background" will need `position: relative` and `z-index: 2` to push them above it. (Like the paragraph in the example below)

#### Example 1

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#000 0%, #FFF 100%) no-repeat;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  top: -220px;
  left: 90px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 20% 50%, #33753E 0%, #003832 100%);
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
div:after {
  top: -220px;
  left: 92px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #003832;
}
p {
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```

#### Example 2 - extended

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#000 0%, #FFF 100%) no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 100px;
  max-width: 1600px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
  top: -200%;
  left: 90px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 20% 50%, #33753E 0%, #003832 100%);
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
div:after {
  left: 92px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #003832;
}
p {
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats amazing, thank you! One quick question though, how would I get this background to carry through to the edge of the page, like it does (partially) on the original code? I was using the after pseudo element to do this.

Comment: @PhilYoung - Basically everything needs to get bigger! I have created a second example for you in my answer. Notice the larger lengths. Remove the width on the div and set a `max-width` that is set at some sane pixel limit. 1600px here.

Comment: @PhilYoung - There is an even better alternative that is easier to work with. I have added that as another option at the top of my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be exactly as you shown on a picture - try :before pseudoclass.

```css
#div_with_background{
 position: relative;
 background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 60% 50%, #33753E 0%, #003832 100%);
 width: 567px;
 height: 356px;
}
#div_with_background:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 356px 0 0px 130px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFFFFF;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_with_background"></div>
```