# text-shadow not rendering in Chrome

Tags: html, css

The code below works in Firefox.

But in Chrome, [text-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) doesn't get rendered. Ar least for me.

```css
#site-title{
  background-color: darkslateblue;
 font-size: 35px;
 display: block;
 animation-name: titleAnimation;
 animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes titleAnimation { 
 from { 
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px dodgerblue;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px yellow;
 } 
 to { 
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px dodgerblue;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px yellow;

 } 
}
```

```html
<center><h1 id="site-title">THIS IS A TEST</h1></center>
```

The code works here on StackOvervlow using Chrome, but not on [my blog](https://breaksome.tech)

Any help is appreciated- Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome text shadow rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046142/google-chrome-text-shadow-rendering)

Comment: No, I read that post before posting myself.

Comment: empty the browser cahe

Comment: No dice. Always went on there in private mode, every refresh was a CTRL + F5.
Cleared it manually now, but the issue persists (as expected).

Comment: is your webapp online ? if so give us the link and the version of chrome you are using maybe you are using an old version (with  prefix) ```-webkit-box-shadow```. iam using chrome too and it works

Comment: yes it definitely works on my chrome Version 80.0.3987.116 (Official Build) (64-bit). It s the title of the blog.  glowing ```Break Some Tech! ```

Comment: You say it works for you? Because for me, it doesn't. Chrome on Android as well as Desktop v80, Regular & Private mode. To reproduce visit [breaksome.tech](https://breaksome.tech) Firefox will render yellow Title, Chrome will not.

Comment: it doesn't work on your blog because you are applying the animationn on the parent of the anchor ```<a>```tag instead of the ```<a>```tag itself.

Comment: On your blog you have 225 lines of CSS repeated verbatim. That may or may not be causing your issue, but it can't be a good thing, and may complicate your debugging process.

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo You found it! Thank you very much! I'd like to mark it as the solution but can't because it's a comment. You are right, this fixed it.

Comment: The answer is there , you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't work on your blog because you are applying the animation on the parent element of the anchor tag instead of the tag itself.

use the following code:

```
#site-title a{
  background-color: darkslateblue;
    font-size: 35px;
    display: block;
    animation-name: titleAnimation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

[image]

Then clean up your code you have repatitions of `#site-title` on line 420 and 68.

[image]